# Auto Created Statistics not getting deleted by Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, statistics

I ran into an error in Sql Server and after resolving it, I am looking for the reason why this was happening.
The situation is that I tried to alter a column in a table like this

```
Alter Table tblEmployee 
Alter Column empDate Date
```

But while running this script, I get the error -

The statistics 'empDate' is dependent on column 'empDate'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN empDate failed because one or more objects access this column.

It turns out that this error was because of a statistic being referenced on this column. I have no script that explicitly creates a statistic, and the error occurred in the production environment, so it must have been auto-created. If it is auto-created, then why isn't Sql Server deleting it by itself? My error was resolved when I dropped the statistic.

I looked at other places and not able to find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked hard at SQL statistics for a few versions, but back when, auto-generated statistics had fairly distinctive names (like "_WA_Sys_00000005_00000037"). If your statistics literally had the name "empDate", then it was almost certainly *not* and auto-created statistics, but something someone created deliberately.